# Simulation with a simple car model in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm currently planning to set up a gazebo simulation for an default gazebo simple car model .I haven't had any luck understanding how to go about making the robot move via external commands (keyboard presses, etc.).

The documentation seems to gloss over this, or at least I can't find where it's described. How would I go about making a robot move in the a Gazebo simulation?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10472/simulation-with-a-simple-car-model-in-gazebo/) by [mangoya](https://answers.ros.org/users/785/mangoya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2011-07-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I am not wrong, you need to implement a gazebo plugin that basically converts the velocity commands of the keyboard teleop to gazebo joint torques or speeds. For that purpose, I would recommend to have a look at:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo_plugins

You will find some gazebo plugins available. I think that GazeboRosDiffdrive is specially interesting for you. It implements a gazebo plugin for a differential robot. You would have to do something similar but for a car-like steering model.

Finally, to add Gazebo extensions to urdf files (where I guess you have modeled your robot), have a look at:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/UnderstandingPR2URDFGazeboExtension

I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [gazkune](https://answers.ros.org/users/165/gazkune/) with karma: 219 on 2011-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mangoya](https://answers.ros.org/users/785/mangoya/) on 2011-07-06**:
Hi @gazkune,

first of all, Thanks for your rapid answer. I've been finding in the gazebo_plugins and I've found gazebo_ros_diffdrive.cpp but I don't understand it. Then Where could i find more documentation or examples about it, because I'm novice

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!
I used this two tutorials of the pr2 and they helped me a lot. Check them out. Hope it helps you:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Using%20the%20robot%20base%20controllers%20to%20drive%20the%20robot

http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Using%20the%20base%20controller%20with%20odometry%20and%20transform%20information

Good luck. I'm also stuck with making a sad car just to move in gazebo so I understand your pain XD.

---

Originally posted by [Aidan1488](https://answers.ros.org/users/777/aidan1488/) with karma: 46 on 2011-07-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mangoya](https://answers.ros.org/users/785/mangoya/) on 2011-07-12**:
thanks, you're vey kind